# TPM 2.0 (TRUSTED PLATFORM MODULE)

Tags: tpm

what is the total number of writes that can be made to a TPM 2.0 compliant module or chip?

Comment: Do you mean the overall amount of bytes that can be written before the TPM storage wears out, or the space available for persistent objects?

Comment: I mean the worst case must be writing the max number of bytes a tpm chip can hold every time we write something into. Considering this scenario what is the number of writes before it wears out beyond which no more writes are possible.

Comment: Isn't this something that would be in the manufacturer's specs?